# No error displayed and files cached with (access denied) error

Tags: aptana3

I have a project which is in a directory which requires Administrator Access on a Windows 7 machine. If I open the file and edit it, I can save it without receiving an error. However, if I then open the file directly from the file system, or using the "System Editor" option, the changes are not present.

If I do this same thing using a Java Eclipse package, it gives me an error when I try to save it.

I can only assume Aptana Studio is caching the save somewhere ? Even if I close Aptana Studio and re-start the computer the cached changes are still visible. But are not found when looking at the file from the "Location:" path of the project.